# MongoMapper and "join tables" with properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have lists of items. The items can belong to multiple lists. This is easily done by defining a many to many relation.

```
class List
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :item_ids, Array
  many :items, :in => :item_ids
end
```

But I also want the lists to be ordered. An item can be on index 2 in one list and index 4 in the other. Normally I would use a join table with a 'position' field, but I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish such a thing with MongoMapper, as everyone seems to advise NOT to use join tables in a no SQL environment (which makes perfect sense).

Is it a good idea to use join tables in MongoDB or does it use another mechanic to accomplish this? And bonuspoints: how do I implement this in MongoMapper?

Answer (score 0):

`item_ids` is an array. As such, it's going to be naturally ordered - you can simply insert items into your `items` association in the order you want them to be in. If you want to re-order them, just sort the `item_ids` array by some criteria and save the document, or sort the items when you consume them from the array.

```
# When consuming the list
@list.items.sort_by &:name

# Or if you want to persist the order
@list.item_ids = @list.items.sort {|item| ... }.map(&:id)
@list.save
```

Comment: Hey Chris, this is the first thing I tried actually, but the id's seem to get reordered by MongoMapper. In the end I took a look at my database design and rewrote it to better fit a nosql solution, but the question still stands. I'll try to update my question with the test I use.

Comment: That sounds like a bug! Array ordering should be preserved. If you can reproduce the issue, please file a bug report at https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/issues